# Sequential reading from a textfile Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Trying to read sequentially from a textfile. However, currently, only the last line is read when the button is clicked. I want to read all questions from the textfile one after the other. Here's my code:

```
   buttonNext.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    public void handle(ActionEvent E){

       java.io.File inFile = new java.io.File("QuestionSheet.txt");


       try {
           java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(inFile);

            while (input.hasNext()){
                String[] lineOfCsv = input.nextLine().split(",");
                questionLabel.setText(lineOfCsv[0]);
                aRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[1]);
                bRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[2]);
                cRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[3]);
                dRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[4]);


            }

        } catch (java.io.IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error reading file " + ex.toString());
        }

       buttonNext.setText("Next Question");

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read each line seperatly keep a reference to the `Scanner` and call `nextLine` only once per button click. However this makes it difficult to make sure the `Scanner` is always properly closed. It would probably be simpler to read the lines to a `List<String>` and iterating through it instead:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("QuestionSheet.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(filePath); // using nio for simplicity here

buttonNext.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

    // iterator for stepwise iterating through the list
    private final Iterator<String> iterator = lines.iterator();

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String[] lineOfCsv = iterator.next().split(",");
            questionLabel.setText(lineOfCsv[0]);
            aRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[1]);
            bRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[2]);
            cRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[3]);
            dRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[4]);
            buttonNext.setDisable(!iterator.hasNext());
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: I understand now the way I was trying to do it was wrong however I'm not fully sure why the line: Path filePath = Paths.get("QuestionSheet.txt"); is saying 'incompatible types: java.nio.file.Path cannot be converted to javafx.scene.shape.Path'. Is this a clash due to JavaFX?

Comment: You have an import to `javafx.scene.shape.Path` or to `javafx.scene.shape.*` instead of importing `java.nio.file.Path`. If you need to use `javafx.scene.shape.Path` in some other part of the file instead of modifying the import you should declare `filePath` using the fully qualified class name i.e. `java.nio.file.Path filePath = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Use buffer reader and input stream to read line by line, The reason is buffer reader contains a default read line function. which helps a lot.

```
buttonNext.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
public void handle(ActionEvent E){
try{
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("QuestionSheet.txt");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  System.out.println (strLine);
  String[] lineOfCsv = strLine.split(",");
  questionLabel.setText(lineOfCsv[0]);
  aRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[1]);
  bRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[2]);
  cRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[3]);
  dRadio.setText(lineOfCsv[4]);
}
in.close();
}catch (Exception e){
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: this is an improvement but probably will not fix the OP's probelm

Comment: The reading will be done line by line and it will be printed out but if he is looking to show them on screen one after another, then labels need to be dynamic [array would be the way to go]